# MySQL Left Join and excluding values

Tags: mysql, join

**UPDATE**

There is a database model in sqfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dbb0/10

And I updated the question according to the annotations.

**Original Post**
I have three tables:

posts
tags
tag_to_post

Lets asume a tag_id 1 that has been used by user 2. Now I want to show user 2 all posts, that another user has tagged with tag_id 1, but user 2 has not tagged with tag_id 1 so far.

The query:

```
SELECT posts.id AS post_id, tags.id AS tag_id, tag_to_post.user_id AS 
user_tagged_post  
FROM posts  
LEFT JOIN tag_to_post ON tag_to_post.post_id = posts.id  
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tag_to_post.tag_id  
WHERE tags.id =1
```

Produces something like:

```
post_id | tags_id | user_tagged_post  
1      | 1       | 1  
1      | 1       | 2  
2      | 1       | 2  
3      | 1       | 1
```

So there should only be left post id 3.

First I tried with where-statement like:

```
WHERE tags.id = 1 AND tag_to_post.user_id != '2'
```

But this of course doesn't exclude post_id 1 cause it is a douplicate. I think there should be a DISTINCT or GROUPED BY before the WHERE clause, but this seems not to be allowed. So the only way is a sub-query? I didn't find a solution so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is `"foo"` in your query?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're trying to do here.  Can you clarify a bit?   Maybe show sample contents for each table and better explain what each column represents.

Comment: Best would be to make a fiddle at sqlfiddle.com with sample data.

Comment: Sorry for beeing unclear: I want to filter out all post ids, that other users have tagged with tag_id 1, but the user with the id 2 has not tagged with the tag_id 1. In this sample data it is post ID 12. I will correct the description and try sqlfiddle

Comment: Ok, I created some test-data in sqlfiddle, great tool: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dbb0/4  Now the aim is to filter out Post 3, because this is the only post that has the tag "bookmarklet" (of user 1) but user 2 has not tagged it with "bookmarklet" so far. Hope this is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it would seem like a straight forward `LEFT JOIN`;

```sql
SELECT t1.post_id, p.title, t1.tag_id, t1.user_id 
FROM tag_to_post t1
JOIN posts p ON t1.post_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN tag_to_post t2
  ON t1.tag_id  = t2.tag_id AND t1.post_id = t2.post_id AND t2.user_id = 2
WHERE t1.user_id <> 2 AND t2.user_id IS NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3384e/1).

Comment: I think that's really straight forward, easy and works. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something like this

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.title, tags.tag, tag_to_post.user_id
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN tag_to_post ON tag_to_post.post_id = posts.id 
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = tag_to_post.tag_id 
WHERE tags.id = 1 AND tag_to_post.user_id <> 2
```

Based on comments:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.id, posts.title, tags.tag, A.user_id
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN tag_to_post A ON A.post_id = posts.id 
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = A.tag_id 
WHERE tags.id = 1
AND A.post_id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM tag_to_post WHERE tags.id = 1 AND user_id = 2)
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, from SQFiddle I get the same problem as above: The query shows post 3 and post 1 that is tagged by user 1. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dbb0/10 But post 1 has already been tagged by user 2, so it should not appear. Problem is that it is a douplicate and the solution would be to make something like a distinct before the where clause. But that doesn't seem to be allowed.

Comment: Ok, look at the second query in the answers

Comment: Thanks Sergey, this works! But I just accepted joachims version cause it works withoud subqueries that I wanted to avoid. Thanks again!